# Change the URL mapping -Javamelody

Tags: servlet-filters, java-melody

I'm using **Javamelody** in my application. I need only root users to access the statistics. Javamelody by default you can access

```
http://localhost/webapp/monitoring
```

I need to change it to

```
http://localhost/webapp/monitor/monitoring
```

I have done the following filter mapping

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>monitoring-path</param-name>
                <param-value>/admin/monitoring</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: inside **<url-pattern>/monitoring</url-pattern>** we write path to monitor. am I right?

Comment: @gstackoverflow No, this is a pattern for all the URLs for which the filter should be applied (URLs to be monitored). Path to monitor is specified as in the answer.