# Change the URL mapping in Javamelody

Tags: servlet-filters, java-melody

I have the same exact problem as in [Change the URL mapping -Javamelody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803638/change-the-url-mapping-javamelody), but unfortunately I cannot comment on it due to lack of reputation.
The accepted answer there does not do it for me and I have a feeling it might be because I am inserting it in the wrong place. Where exactly do I need to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem as such:

The .jar files from Javamelody need to be in the lib folder of your webapp, not only in your tomcat\lib folder.

Then I added this code to the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>monitoring-path</param-name>
            <param-value>/admin/monitoring</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



 <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>W2MO</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>

            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>admin</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

    <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            <realm-name>JavaMelody Monitoring</realm-name>
    </login-config>
  <security-role>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

The admin role needs to be defined in the file tomcat-users.xml:

```
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin"/>
```