# JavaMelody mapping URL

Tags: java, spring, mapping, servlet-filters, java-melody

I'm trying to install Javamelody in my Spring application. I configured on localhost and can access Javamelody with URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/myapp/stats
```

Server: webSphere 7.0 and my web.xml config is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="myapp">
    <display-name>myapp</display-name>      
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:net/bull/javamelody/monitoring-spring.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>        

    <filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>monitoring-path</param-name>
             <param-value>/stats</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>       

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>myapp.web.AppInit</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javascript</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <display-name>page</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>unificator</servlet-name>
        <display-name>unificator</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webservicesoap</servlet-name>
        <display-name>webservicesoap</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javascript</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/validation.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>unificator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>unificator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>unificator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/contacts/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

However, this config in production environment is not working. If I go to

```
http://app.gtrwe.dev.corp/myapp/stats
```

I get 404 error. Also I have servlets in my web.xml

I am looking for help on how to set this up.

Comment: Could you add the servlets mapping to your post?

Comment: @hasnae Added configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the URL mapping -Javamelody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803638/change-the-url-mapping-javamelody)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IBM WebSphere  may encounter the ERROR 404 if no servlet is mapped to either /* or /monitoring, as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/issues/detail?id=103)

Comment: Thanks @hasnae, but I do not have access to the server in production...other solution?

Comment: You can use WebServlet annotation, but it's only available since servlet 3.0

Comment: WebSphere 7.0 don't support servlet 3.0.

Comment: but why is work in my local machine with the same WebSphere version?